# "SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal " when i run python code to save data in sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite

I want to save data in sqlite database , the data is @function and size , block size and dump ( extracting and read @size bytes from @f & return data ) this data are obtained by analysis of binary file.
[Screenshot shwing the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbuzP.png)

```
 try:
                con = lite.connect('younes.db')
                c = con.cursor()
                c.execute(" CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  disas(NAMEvarchar(20),STADDR INTEGER,BLOCK INTEGER, DUMP BLOB )")

                c.execute("INSERT INTO disas VALUES ('"+f.name+"', "+str(f.addr)+", "+str(b.size)+",'"+dump+"')

    except lite.Error, e:
            if con:
                con.rollback()
                print "Error %s:" % e.args[0]
                sys.exit(1)
    finally:
             if con:
                c.close()
                con.close()


  File "testy.py", line 58
        c.execute("INSERT INTO disas VALUES ('"+f.name+"', "+str(f.addr)+", "+str(b.size)+",'"+dump+"')^
     SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

Comment: `dump+" '` -> `dump+" ' "`

Comment: thank you , but it generates  the same error

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a closing `"` also a closing `)` inside the string.

Should be something like:

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO disas VALUES ('" + f.name + "', " + str(f.addr) + ", " + str(b.size) + ",'" + dump + "')")
```

It would be a lot easier to read your string if you did something like:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO disas VALUES ('{name}', '{addr}', '{size}', '{dump}')".format(
    name=f.name,
    addr=f.addr,
    size=b.size,
    dump=dump
)
c.execute(sql)
```

That's easier to read and easier to catch where you went wrong.

Comment: I think you'd better let sqlite3 module to handle that value parsing: c.execute('INSERT INTO disas VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)', f.name, f.addr, b.size, dump)